# SSRS TimeStamp incorrect format when exported to Excel

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a datetimestamp field in SSRS, when I preview the report the data looks okay (2015-06-23 1:33:00 PM), but when I export the report to excel it creates ############### and not showing the date time.  The dataset is done in SQL query cast(m.CallTime as datetime).  What I want to happen is to display just the time in SSRS and Excel (1:30 PM). Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to expand the width of the column in Excel?

Comment: This is because the column width is too short for the content. Open your report in SSRS Management Studio and increase the column width.

Comment: It should be inherited from ssrs since i formatted it as time in ssrs, but i did a chessy expression RIGHT(<field>, 5)

Answer (score 0):

I've always had issues with the Excel export with date formats but I think that's more due to Excel propensity to guess wrong at the format I want. Why is it whenever I have a date with no time, it usually is formatted as time only (0:00)? Very annoying.

Make sure that your date is in a date format. You casted it in your query but you could also use CDATE to do it in SSRS.

Set the format using the Textbox's **FORMAT** Property to **hh:mm tt** .

It should come out as specified in Excel.